# Rendering image with overlay Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, image-rendering

I'm building a Drupal website and I need to upload an image, some text and render that image with the text as overlay, maybe even a logo on top of it as well. Is there a module or a way to do this on Drupal 8?

Clarification: I need to generate a new picture and add overlay as pixel data.

Comment: I need to be able to export it.

Comment: Please, clarify your question: do you simply need to put some overlay elements on top of <img> element, or you need to generate a new picture and add overlay as pixel data (watermarks)?

Comment: I need to generate a new picture and add overlay as pixel data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Image Effects](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_effects) module. According to [readme](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/image_effects/tree/README.md#n6) it provides both - text overlay and watermark effects. If they are not sufficient for your needs you also have "ImageMagick arguments" effect, so nothing can stop you now ))